# Clicking on Href Button selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have delt with an Href button in the past and didn't find it too hard, but this button is being a pain. I have tried clicking by xpath, class, and link text. None have worked. I know there are plenty of the same question out there, but most of them give answer's that I am already trying. Below is the code I have. The one thing I haven't tried is javascriptexecutor. I also have been clicking on it in the command line of chrome and it does work. Just can't get selenium too. It throws an element not found. Also I feel it is worthy to note that I did not find any IFrames that I need to switch to. The only things that concern me which maybe I do not have the knowledge of selenium to deal with is the HTML mentions `header`, `main`, `section`, `div`, `ul`, `li` , and `a` which I have seen all before except for `ul` and `li`. Thank you for any help someone provides.

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("card-header-link float-md-right"))).Click();
```

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div/ul/li[5]/a"))).Click(); //full xpath
```

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/main/section[1]/div/ul/li[5]/a"))).Click();
```

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("Security"))).Click();
```

HTML

```
<li data-v-91f16f3e="">
    <a data-v-91f16f3e="" href="/security" class="">
        <span data-v-91f16f3e="" class="icon icon-shield"></span> 
        <span data-v-91f16f3e="" class="text">Security</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this xpath :

```
//span[text()='Security']/..
```

or

```
//span[text()='Security']/parent::a[@href='/security']
```

in code :

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()='Security']/.."))).Click();
```

but it is strange to know that `By.LinkText("Security")` did not work.

**Update 1 :**

**try this css selector**

```
 div[class$='desktop'] li a[href$='security']
```

**code :**

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div[class$='desktop'] li a[href$='security']"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the `href` attribute value is lowercased `security`, not `Security`.
So, please try this:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//a[contains(@href,'security')]"))).Click();
```

Comment: Well he never tried href with `Security` though !

Comment: But it seems to be similar to `By.LinkText()` method

Comment: no the text is `Security` not `security`, so `By.LinkText("Security")` would have worked but it's strange.